# Whether or not to drop the subject after "than"

Tags: comparative-constructions

I wrote this sentence:

> The result of the treatment will be less effective than (that) would be achieved by aspirin being added.

I have noticed that, in many sentences, the subject after *than* are often dropped,  but I'm not sure in which case I should do that.

I want to make sure if the sentence is correct without **that**

Comment: You can't just add "that" with no further changes. Valid alternatives include *...less effective than **that which** would be achieved by aspirin* and *...less effective than **that** achieved by aspirin*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is it valid if I don't add "that" in the first place, ie,... than would be achieved by aspirin...

Comment: Yes. As you said in your question text, the "repeated subject" (***that***, referring back to earlier ***result***) is often dropped. For example, there are many written instances of *[Something is] [**less effective than would be**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22less+effective+than+would+be%22) [expected]*, where *in principle* we could use *...than **that which** would be...*, but in practice we usually / often don't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I get it, thanks.

Comment: Either don't add anything, or add ***what*** (not ***that***).